# Cron Job Hourly Except Certain Time Frame on Friday

Tags: shell, shell-script, cron, scheduling

I want my cron job to run every hour, every day except Friday when I don't want it to run at all between the hours of 2am-9am (but hourly outside of this timeframe). Ideally, I'd like to have this in one line/one cron job. What I have so far is 2 lines (and I'm not 100% sure it is correct):

```
0 0 * * 0,1,2,3,4,6 script.sh
0 0-1,10-23 * * 5 script.sh
```

Comment: Other than one minor correction to the first line, as in `0 * * * 0,1,2,3,4,6 script.sh`, your two lines of crontab entries should do the job. I am not up to speed with the newest addition to the cron configuration, but the basic cron functionality, doesn't provide an _exclusion_ directive. 3rd party job scheduling tools can provide that functionality. Tivoli Maestro is one that comes to mind off the top of my head. I am sure there are some open source ones out there. This is a very useful page to look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software

Comment: @MelBurslan, thanks, that works perfectly. These 3rd party tools are interesting, and I'll keep them in mind for future projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format seems to be correct (after correction applied posted in the comment above). Are there some special restrictions for having everything in a single line? In case you need to have everything in a single line, I would suggest to change the shell script to avoid Fridays 2-9am, eg

```
#!/bin/bash
# THIS CODE IS NOT TESTED
# skip on fridays 2-9am
# what are the non-running times?
STARTTIME=2
ENDTIME=9

# get the current day of the week
DAY=$(date +"%u") # 1-Monday, therefore 5-Friday
# and the hour
HOUR=$(date +"%H")

if [ "$DAY" -eq 5 -a "$HOUR" -ge "$STARTTIME" -a "$HOUR" -le "$ENDTIME" ]
then
   # end the execution
   exit 0
fi
```

Hope that helps to solve the issue!

Frank

Comment: Thanks! No, there aren't any special restrictions in place limiting me to having only one line, but I just thought it would be more aesthetic.